# What are some terms which could be used to refer to the entities involved in a relationship?

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, models, entities, conceptual

E.g. parent/child is an obvious one, where the parent is the key holder and the child has a reference to that key.

Another example would be as in Entity Framework, "End 1" and "End 2" but this doesn't specify which "end" is the owner of the key.

Perhaps another could be "owning entity" and "referencing entity".

I'm interested to know more examples of this, specifically examples which have a clear "owner" e.g. the entity which defines the start of the relationship, if that makes sense.

Comment: Base and Derived. Generic and Instance. However these are limited to single hierarchical derivation. Parent, child is the most robust as it can be extended to grandchild, grandparent, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but ... both of those sets of terms describe inheritance, not encapsulation (not the correct term but I think you will get what I mean). E.g. the child end of a relationship or foreign key is not 'derived' from the parent ('base'). The child end simply contains a reference to the parent end.

Comment: It depends on your implementation. In code (my go to) traditionally a child IS derived from the parent, but I see you are looking for encapsulation only. Perhaps Leader/Owner & members would be a better relationship example then. It sounds like you are describing an array/map/vector relationship where there is a singular owner or container and there are other items which are grouped via that owner/container.

Answer (score 1):

I think any combination of Root/Super and Leaf/Child/Offspring/Sub would probably work. I personally like Root/Sub, since it applies regardless of where on the tree you are and isn't Parent/Child.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sir.